# How can I connect MATRICOM wireless controller to raspberry pi 3?

Tags: bluetooth, wireless, retropie

I bought 2 wireless controller from amazon called MATRICOM to connect them to my raspberry pi 3 running retropie 4.2

This controller works for PC, Android, PS3.
It has a mode button so I can change the mode to keyboard or mouse or controller. I connected it via bluetooth and when i configured it as a controller everything goes fine but in games I can use only the arrows. When I configured it as a keyboard I can use only one controller because both of them keyboard and they work as one keyboard, but there is a problem with this also, the 1st controller I connect it will have issue with the buttons (like when I pressed the arrow to move, it also press a button to jump or to fire what ever the game is)  but the 2nd controller works fine.  If I connect the 2nd controller first, the 1st controller will have the issue, whatever the controller I connect it first will have the issue but the second one will bot have this issue.

I want to connect it as a ps3 controller and I tried all ps3 controller drivers and it is not connected. When I remove the cable and run the controller, the lights blinks but not connected wirelessly.

Note: when I connect it via usb it shows that I connect an xbox 360 controller.

I connect them to a pc and they worked fine with no issues.

How can I connect them to my raspberry pi 3 via bluetooth without any issue??

[image]